# scheduleAtFixRate runs every 10 minutes instead of hourly

Tags: java, tomcat9, servletcontextlistener

I have created a job to run every hour as follows

```
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        .
        .
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HourlyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But `HourlyJob()` is executing every 10 minutes instead of hourly. Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Does anyone know why the `TimeUnit.HOURS` is not considered as expected?

Comment: That would be very strange. Can you confirm the code that it is running on tomcat is the correct one?

Comment: I am running the code on Tomcat via Eclipse

Comment: If that was indeed the case, I would suggest you to execute it and log the output with time displayed on two settings 1. On normal Java program, 2. On eclipse’s tomcat to find out what causes the problem. Then you can submit a bug report to the party

Answer (score 0):

It may be an annotation for scheduled task's method **@Schedule**

```
@Schedule(hour = "*")
public void doHourlyJob() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I am not using any annotation. Only annotations I have used so far are WebListener and WebServlet. This is plane java project, not using spring or any other framework